# Passing more than one variables from different controllers to a single view in Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller, routes

I need to pass two variables from two different controllers to a view and display the different values from the array variables to two different html form's select options in Laravel 8. But Laravel doesn't seem to allow pass two differnt variable to a single view.

How do I slove this?

[Please find the error screenshot from this link.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9lYFV.png)

Controllers involved: TimeController, CourseController

**Time Controller:**

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Time;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class TimeController extends Controller
{
    public function loadTime()
    {
        $timeData = DB::table('time')->select('*')->get();
        return view('admin.forms.enrollment', ['timeList' => $timeData]);
    }
}
```

**CourseController:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class CourseController extends Controller
{
    public function loadCourses()
    {
        $courseData = DB::table('courses')->select('*')->get();
        return view('admin.forms.enrollment', ['courseList' => $courseData]);

        // $timeData = DB::table('time')->select('*')->get();
        // return view('admin.forms.enrollment', ['timeList' => $timeData]);
    }
}
```

**Routes:**

```
Route::get('/enroll', [TimeController::class, 'loadTime'])->name('loadTime');
Route::get('/enroll', [CourseController::class, 'loadCourses'])->name('loadCourses');
```

**View:**

```
@extends('admin.forms.layout')

@section('form')

<div class="form-group row">
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <label for="lastname" class="col-sm-6 col-form-label">Username</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="uname" placeholder="eg. Khatri0b3d020d">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <label for="course" class="col-sm-6 col-form-label">Course</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <select name="course" id="course" class="form-control">
              
            @foreach($courseList as $course)

                <option value="{{$course->vehicle_category}}">{{$course->course_type}}</option>

              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row">
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <label for="email" class="col-sm-6 col-form-label">Package</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="eg. khatriram55@gmail.com">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <label for="phone" class="col-sm-6 col-form-label" value="+977">Start Date</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="date" class="form-control" id="date" min="{{date('Y-m-d')}}">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row">
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <label for="time" class="col-sm-6 col-form-label">Preferred Time</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <select name="time" id="time" class="form-control">
                <option selected default>Select your preferred time</option>
                
                @foreach($timeList as $time)

                <option value="{{$time->id}}">{{$time->time}}</option>

                @endforeach 

              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row">
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <input type="submit" value="Admit" name="admit" class="btn btn-success">
          </div>
</div>

@endsection
```

Comment: Why do you need same view for two different controllers ??

Comment: I am new to MVC pattern and Laravel. I am learning the concepts and working on a personal project alongside.

Actually what I am trying to do is fetch the time data from the time table and courses data from the course table and display it on a single view.

Comment: So you need both ```courses``` table data and ```time``` table data into single view right

Comment: Yes. The view is basically a form for student enrollment. The time table contains the list of time (7 am, 8 am, etc) and the course table contains tha list of courses. The form requires to load the time and courses data in select options for time and courses field respectively.

Comment: Create a `CoursesAndTimeController` does both things and pass both results to the view. (note this is one of the potentially dozens of ways to do this, don't just do it because some guy on the internet said so)

Comment: I would advise you to take a look at how routes work in Laravel. A route points to one controller, and one function of that controller. If you create 2 routes with the same URL, only one of the two will work.

Comment: @GertB. thank you. I should really develop a habit of going through the documentations. It's not that I don't go through the documentations at all but when I have to make a lot of readings and redirect to multiple links I feel like not going through the texts.

Any suggestion on reading documentations correctly or efficiently or anything that you'd like to add?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So based on your comment I understand your issue. And you don't need Two controllers and seperate routes.

Create a New controller with name of `StudentEnrollmentController` by running

`php artisan make:controller StudentEnrollmentController` and paste the below code into controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Time;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class StudentEnrollmentController extends Controller
{
    public function showEnrollmentForm()
    {
        $timeData = DB::table('time')->get();
        $courseData = DB::table('courses')->get();
        return view('admin.forms.enrollment', compact('timeData', 'courseData'));
    }
}
```

Add following line to `routes/web.php`

```
Route::get('/enrollmentForm', [App\Http\Controllers\App\Http\Controllers::class, 'showEnrollmentForm'])->name('enrollmentForm');
```

Now visit the URL `enrollmentForm` it will Display the form without errors.